# Vagrant not mapping to folder Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ssh

I am attempting to create my laravel environment with homestead. I do vagrant up and it seems to work fine, however when I vagrant ssh there are no folders inside my vagrant.

I have a folder named 'Code' in my home directory.

I am using Ubuntu. Here is my yaml file.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: /Users/pocockn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/pocockn/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/pocockn/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, use the `~` symbol to specify the home folder and then the folders you are going to use, something like the next example.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```